# Is there something wrong with vite hot reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm relatively new to using vite for react (started using it 3 months ago). I have never had any problem with the hmr until now. It keeps refresing the whole page everytime i make changes to my code.

I'm utterly confused that I don't know what went wrong or how I can describe this issue better.

Comment: Do you have auto-save toggled in your IDE?

Comment: Yes the auto-save is active, is that what's causing this?

Comment: Well, HMR is triggered by a save in the codebase so I would say yes. I guess... turn it off and find out what happens.